# How to save Eclipse project programticaly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I need to save project file programmatically before closing it, how can I achieve it? any hints will be more than welcome!

manually save means when the user modifies the project, usually, they have to click File->Save

```
          List<IProject> projectList = new LinkedList<IProject>();

        IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
         IProject[] projects = workspaceRoot.getProjects();
         for(int i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            IProject project = projects[i];
            if(project.isOpen()) {
               project.close(new org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor());
            }
         }
```

Comment: What do mean by 'save' it? Once created projects don't need to be saved.

Comment: save mean when user modify the project, usually, they have to click File->Save , i want to do it programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can save all editors for files in a project using:

```
IDE.saveAllEditors(new IResource [] {project}, confirm);
```

where `confirm` is `true` if you want a confirmation prompt, `false` otherwise.

`IDE` is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE`